# Linuxmint in virtualbox not booting to mint os

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, boot-loader, busybox

I was running linux mint in virtual box but today when I rebooted it landed in Busybox i tried reboot it lands in busybox.. i do not know what to doo next.

[image]

i really need to get it working i have mysql database on it.. or i will loose it.

Answer (score 0):

from initramfs menu I ran fsck /dev/sda1 which fixed filesystem and then I typed reboot and I was able to boot to linuxmint 19 normally in vbox. completely bizarre a disk can get correupted inside of virtual box.